# Перенос сайта с joomla на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Добрый вечер.

Пытаюсь перенести сайт с joomla на wordpress, 5 часов пытаюсь по разному вбить настройки, облазил кучу сайтов и форумов и все как один говорят, что я правильно все вбиваю...однако все не работает...
что тут не так?
Port и пароль брал из "FTP пользователи" так же дополнительно скачал configuration.php с сайта joomla[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем вы в порт IP-адрес вбили?...по умолчанию порт MySQL - 3306 ...попробуйте его

Comment: плюс, если у Вас сайты на разных серверах, то вряд ли Вы сможете с любого места подключиться к БД. В Мускуле может быть прописано с каких хостов, Вы можете к нему обращаться и не имея доступов к администрированию MySQL выэтого обойти не сможете.

Comment: АЛИЛУЯЯ)))) блокировка на хосте стояла))))) и поставил порт 3306 АЛИЛУЯ))) СПАСИБИЩЕЕЕ))) спасибище!!!! огромнешее)))) я прям обожаю вас)))))) ОБОЖАЮ!!!!))) спасибо!!!))!)!)!))!))!)

Comment: Хорошие картинки.. Правда не понятен их источник, но эт ладно...  Осталось только пароль открыто написать, что бы взломщики не мучались брутом..